# Mixing WebForms and MVC: What should I do with the MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, webforms, mixed-mode

I want to start migrating a WebForms App to MVC. The process will be gradual, so both systems must co-exist.

The question is: **Should I have two MasterPages, one for the WebForms pages and other for the MVC views? Is there a way to have only one?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC the master page should derive from [`System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.aspx) while in classic WebForms from [`System.Web.UI.MasterPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx). If in MVC you use the latter you won't have access to any helpers. Although you could use `ViewMasterPage` in classic webforms because it derives from `MasterPage` (once again you won't have access to helpers in the web forms application but who cares).

So to answer your question, yes, you could have a common master page assuming it derives from `ViewMasterPage`.

This being said you probably won't be able to make this work as in an MVC master page you would use HTML helpers to render partial views like `Html.RenderPartial` which doesn't make much sense in a classic WebForms application and vice versa in a classic WebForms application you would probably be using some server side controls like `<asp:xxx runat="server" />` or have a single `form` tag (again with `runat="server"`) polluted with ViewState, etc... which hardly makes any sense in MVC. So my recommendation would be not to do like this.

Comment: So, your recommendation is to have two MasterPages? (It's no big deal, since it do not change often)

Comment: Yes, this is my recommendation. There are cases where duplication is better rather than trying to much reuse and end up with a clone (the nature has created different species and trying to mix them could lead to unexpected results :-)).