# WebForms inside an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I created an ASP.NET MVC 2 website and a classic ASP.NET WebForms to let the client to deal with the data (SQL Server).

Now, because of budget reasons, I´m forced to mix them together in one only web site. I read a lot of tutorials about the inverse situation, but haven´t found a clue on how to use my old **webforms inside a MVC 2 project**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can check this reply 
[Mixing webforms and mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578045/mixing-webforms-and-mvc-what-should-i-do-with-the-masterpage)

and also scott hanselman blog [Mixed mode for webforms and mvc3](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)